# NuxtJS jQuery and Bootstrap elements doesn't works

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I bought Bootstrap theme on official website and I try to integrate it with **VueJS** and **NuxtJS** (*v2.8.1*).

## My nuxt.config.ts file

```
head: {
    title: 'title',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'description' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons',
      },
    ],
    script: [
      {
        src: '/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        type: 'text/javascript',
        body: true,
        defer: true,
      },
      {
        src: '/assets/vendor/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js',
        type: 'text/javascript',
        body: true,
        defer: true,
      },
      {
        src: '/assets/vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js',
        type: 'text/javascript',
        body: true,
        defer: true,
      },
      {
        src: '/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
        type: 'text/javascript',
        body: true,
        defer: true,
      }
    ],
  },
```

I'm on login page, the website has been loading. The website works and I can sign in to dashboard. Once on the dashboard, the **Bootstrap** elements (*like the dropdown or slider*) are not loaded, they do not work.

**If I refresh the web page, everything works but I have a warning...**

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

This is not the source of my problem. I deleted the part of the code that generates this warning.

On the other hand, if I refresh the page, all Bootstrap elements work. While from one page to another, the elements are blocked.

Comment: That error means that, somewhere, you are calling `JSON.parse()` on an object, not a JSON-encoded string.

Comment: This is not the source of my problem. I deleted the part of the code that generates this warning.

On the other hand, if I refresh the page, all Bootstrap elements work. While from one page to another, the elements are blocked.